Miter Cuts to achieve an 8 ft diameter
I am looking to segment wood pieces together to make a circular frame around an above ground pool. The diameter of the pool is 8 feet. What is the least number of boards I can use to achieve this and make it round? What would the mitered cut angles be to seam together and overall length of each board needed? TIA!

Angles != round. What is the outer shape (round? square? rectangle?) of the frame? What is the outer size of the frame? Making a 16' square is very different from making a 12' circle, even though they both have an 8' circle inside. For the part up against the pool you might need to do something like lay out the boards on a flat surface, draw a circle (one nail, a 4' string and a marker will do) and then use a jigsaw to cut the circle.

What material are you planning to make this frame out of?

3, for a triangular approximation of "round" - other wise "infinite" is what it takes for round-from-segments. Anything less is an approximation. Straight segments make polygons.
1 could work with round-from-bending but it's hard to find 25+ foot long individual boards. 12 & 14 foot are easier to find, though.

See also: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/14499/6806

If you're going to steam bend, with a well made fixture you could certainly produce enough identical parts to use any size lumber to start
